# Someone being pulled from a shallow pit

Tags: nature, cloth, foley-stage

Here's the scene, a man steps down and the ground gives way. He falls into a pit about waist height. Two friends help pull the man out, so I was going to do some dragging dirt footsteps sounds but I also want dirt falling away and maybe cloth rubbing against the ground. Any suggestions?

edit:
it's more like a dry hole, but very shallow. Haven't tried it yet with just dirt and cloth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well... you pretty much said it yourself. Messing with cloth (maybe medium heavy canvas/denim) and dirt? Add pebbles? Wet dirt? Dry dirt? Is it like a sink hole? Or just a hole?

Comment: perfect! that worked well actually, I found out if I roll two ping pong balls together in one hand it replicates cloth sounds reasonably well so I don't have to try to hold an entire shirt or jacket or pants in one hand and drop dirt with the other. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it worked. Ping pong balls eh?